# Vandermonde matrix and polynomials

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Question attached as image, deals with polynomials of order N and determinant of 
Vanderbilt matrix.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you type it in latex ?

Comment: This is a special type of Toeplitz matrix called [ciculant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). You have the eigenvalues in this wiki link, hence the dterminant.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,mate .